# Laravel Homestead Multiple Sites

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I have installed Laravel Homestead correctly, but now I want to add an additional site. I've done every step in the documentation, including editing my `Homestead.yaml` and my `hostfile`:

**Homestead.yaml**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: scp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/scp
    - map: katniss.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/katniss

databases:
    - scp

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

**hostfile**

```
192.168.10.10 scp.dev
192.168.10.10 katniss.dev
```

But when I run `vagrant provision` it displays this:

> A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
>   command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
>   get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
>   this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
>   Vagrantfile and to try again.

Do I have to run this command on a specific folder?

Comment: Run the command in your specific Homestead folder.

Comment: And if I have installed it globally ?

Comment: I'm assuming you use Linux or OSX. You should run your command in `~/.homestead` folder. Or *maybe* `homestead update` command might do what you want, but it would take longer because it restarts the vm.

Comment: I just realised that, vagrant commands don't work in `~/.homestead` folder. According to Bogdan's answer we should run it in `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead` but I tried that and it ignores your Homestead configuration. So this isn't the option. I also tried `homestead update` and it tries to update Homestead's box image. So I did an `homestead halt` followed by a `homestead up`. Ugly workaround, but works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `vagrant provision` without an ID requires the working directory to have a `Vagrantfile` generated with `vagrant init`. So for the command to work you need to:

```
cd /directory/with/Vagrantfile
vagrant provision
```

If you want to run the command from anywhere in your system, you can use any vagrant command that takes a target machine (such as `up`, `halt`, `destroy`, `provision`) with the ID of that machine. To get the available IDs just run:

```
vagrant global-status
```

And then:

```
vagrant provision MachineID
```

For more info check out the [Vagrant Global Status Docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/global-status.html).

Answer (score 1):

**A simpler one-command solution!**

I stopped editing the homestead.yaml file, because like you I had a hard time getting changes to pick up. Now I just add new sites from within the VM itself. It's really easy, and the best part is that you don't need to re-provision your VM.

**Simply SSH into your Homestead box:**

```
vagrant ssh
```

**Then, use the following command:**

```
serve domain.com ~/Code/project/public
```

Obviously replacing `domain.com` with the domain you want to access the site via, and `~/Code/project/public` with the full path of the public directory of your project.

Don't forget to then also edit your local hosts file, to add `domain.com`:

```
192.168.10.10 domain.com
```

With that done, your new site is now accessible via `domain.com`.

On newer versions of Homestead, the `serve` command may not be available. You can add it back, by going to your `Homestead/scripts/` directory, and copying the `serve-laravel.sh` file to `serve.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution would be.

EPOCLAB:~ Dev$ homestead halt
EPOCLAB:~ Dev$ homestead up --provision

Answer (score 0):

You can use below option.

**homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
- map: ~/Projects/scp
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/scp
- map: ~/Projects/katniss
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/katniss

sites:
- map: scp.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/scp
- map: katniss.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/katniss
```

**hostfile**

```
192.168.10.10 scp.dev
192.168.10.10 katniss.dev
```

Assuming, your homestead was already halted, please run below command.

```
homestead up --provision
```

Try to access your new site again.